# nextjs - useContext Cannot destructure property 'user' of 'Object(…)(…)' as it is null

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, next.js, use-context

I'm getting an error when I try to use useContext with next.js
Here I create the context:

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';

const FirebaseContext = createContext(null);

export default FirebaseContext;
```

This is my index file:

```
import firebase from './firebase';
import FirebaseContext from './context';

export {FirebaseContext};

export default firebase;
```

This is my _app.js:

```
import firebase, { FirebaseContext } from '../firebase';
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth';

const MyApp = props => {
    const user = useAuth();
    const { Component, pageProps } = props;

    return (
        <FirebaseContext.Provider
            value={{
                firebase,
                user
            }}
        >
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </FirebaseContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

and here I'm using the context

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { FirebaseContext } from '../../firebase';
...
const {user, firebase} = useContext(FirebaseContext);
```

I'm looking and the context work, but its like I can't access to the data:

[image]

Any idea what may be going on?

Comment: Are you certain the component where the context is being consumed is a child of `FirebaseContext.Provider`?

Comment: That's the error, my Header was not a child of the context provider, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your problem;

const firebaseContext = useContext(FirebaseContext);

and you can use firebaseContext?.user or firebaseContext?.firebase; instead of destructuring.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).